# error C3861: Identifier Not found for function in DLL, but other functions are found.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, c++-cli, clr

I'm new to Visual C++ and I'm trying to use a DLL produced by another Visual Studio solution.

One of the functions in the DLL works perfectly fine in my new solution, but another gives an error saying `error C3861: Identifier Not found`.

The header file for the DLL looks like this:

```
#ifdef CONVERTLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define CONVERTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)

#include "../Convert/Parse.h"
#include "../Convert/TxI16Types.h"
#include "../Convert/messages.h"

#else
#define CONVERTLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)

#include "Parse.h"
#include "TxI16Types.h"
#include "messages.h"

#endif



extern CONVERTLIBRARY_API long nConvertLibrary;

CONVERTLIBRARY_API int fnConvertLibrary(void);

CONVERTLIBRARY_API int fslParseByte(unsigned char inchr, struct ParseState *ps, unsigned char *outbuf, int outsize);
CONVERTLIBRARY_API int fslCheckMessage(unsigned char* buf, struct ParseState *ps);
CONVERTLIBRARY_API int fslBinaryToAscii(const unsigned char* hdr, char *out, unsigned int outlen, int *error);
CONVERTLIBRARY_API int fslAsciiToBinary(const char* hdr, unsigned char *out, unsigned int outlen, int *error);
```

I have specified the path to the `.lib` file, and this must be correct because I can call the function `fslParseByte`, but calling either `fslAsciiToBinary` or `fslBinaryToAscii` gives my the error.

I'm not sure how this is possible and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It is a compiler error, not a linker error, so the .lib file is not relevant. Occam's razor says that you are #including the wrong file, an old one. The #include directives you use now are bizarre, don't do that.  Surely what got you into trouble, you've been copying .h files to keep the compiler happy and now you have different versions of them.  The correct way to do it is to have only *one* place to store the .h files and tell the compiler about it for client projects with Project + Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories setting.  The Linker has one too for .lib files.

Comment: After reverting all my changes and adding the headers all from a single place the build worked nicely.